# How to append the dependable API in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, json

```
 <body ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-change="getData(currentSelected)" class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelected" ng-options="selection as selection for selection in data">
    <option value="" selected>Select the bankname</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-change="getData(currentSelectedstate)"  class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelectedstate" ng-options="my.state as my.state for my in newdata">
    <option value="" selected>Select the state</option>
    </select>
    <select ng-change="getData1(currentSelecteddistrict)"  class="form-control" id="selection" ng-model="currentSelecteddistrict" ng-options="my.district as my.district for my in data1">
    <option value="" selected>Select the district</option>
    </select>
    </body>
    JS code    
<script>
    var app=angular.module("mainApp",[]);
    app.controller("myController", ["$scope", "$http",function ($scope,$http){
        $http.get("company.in/ifsc/banklist").then(function(response){
            $scope.data=response.data[0].data;
        });
        $scope.getData = function(name){

            $http.get("company.in/ifsc/state/" +name).then(function(response) {
                scope.newdata = response.data;
            });
        }
        $scope.getData1= function(name1){
            $http.get("company.in/ifsc/district/"+banklist+, +name).then(function(response) {
                $scope.data1 = response.newdata;
            });
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

First two API are working fine, When i select particular state in second drop down its not taking the value , How to append fetched bankname and state to the third API? so that i get the list of district in the third drop down....,I'm getting state value as null once i select the state..
Anyone please help how to append the third API?
Thank you

Comment: the URL in the third api looks wrong, should it be `"company.in/ifsc/district/banklist"+name`?

Comment: First selected bankname and second selected state should get appended @TianzhenLin